# How to get more than one query from user in Django

Tags: django

I want to get two query Items from user (In this case two state Id ) and show related value of both(In this case cities of state1 and 2)
I created this view:

```
 def get(self,request,State_id1,State_id2):
    cities = city.objects.filter(state__in= [State_id1,State_id2])
```

but it seems it has some problem.How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd be better off putting them in a URL param, I'm sure you dont want to have something like http://example.org/california/arizona/new-york/...../texas/washington/ and on and on.
Something of http://example.org/?states=california,new-york,texas,washington would make more sense. In this case you don't have to do this.

```
def get(self,request,State_id1,State_id2):
    cities = city.objects.filter(state__in= [State_id1,State_id2])
```

You can do, in this case I'm inheriting APIView, I dont know how you implemented yours.

```
class ClassViewName(APIView):
    def get(self,request):
        states = [state for state in self.request.query_params.get('state').split(',')]
        cities = city.objects.filter(state__in= states)
```

In your app url patterns

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('add-state/', views.ClassViewName.as_view())
]
```

Assuming that this urls.py file is in some app named 'test', and in the main urls.py file we have

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/test', include('test.urls'))
]
```

And if I'm going to hit this endpoint, I'll hit http://example.com/api/test/add-state/?states=california,texas

Comment: Ok let me see if I get it right,by this code:cities = city.objects.filter(state__in= request.GET.getlist('states')) ,states will fill with all the quiries that user asks?
And now,how can I define a path for it?

Comment: You can define any path for example,

`path('add-state/', views.ClassViewName.as_view())`

Then if you are going to include the options, you have somthing like 
http://.../add-state/?states=california,texas,washington

Comment: Well actualyy I dont get this path, in related path user should enter a list of selected states and api show related cities

Comment: Okay. let me update my answer if it would be clearer

Comment: I finally find my answer,your request should be like this:http://.../add-state/?states=california&states=texas&states=washington